# jquery code with [id*=btnSubmit]

Tags: jquery

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {

    string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
    }

    // more stuff...
}
```

Can someone please explain what the jquery code is doing.
I am confused about this part especially :

```
string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
```

Comment: [id*=btnSubmit] finds all elements whose id's contain the text `btnSubmit`

Comment: so having that in my page load simply fires the click event of any btnSubmit buttton(s) when the page loads?...

Comment: yes. It will fire the click event on every button that has `btnSubmit` inside it's id attribute when the document is ready. ( the quickest event possible ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the page loaded

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

apply click event for all buttons with id contains string btnSubmit

```
 $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click();
```

Comment: so in my case is it simply firing the click event when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

> This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match
>   against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string
>   appears anywhere within the element's attribute value. Compare this
>   selector with the Attribute Contains Word selector (e.g.
>   [attr~="word"]), which is more appropriate in many cases.

Basically, `$('[id*=btnSubmit]')` would find all of the following html elements:

```
<div id="btnSubmit"></div>
<div id="btnSubmit2"></div>
<div id="mybtnSubmit"></div>
```

The rest of the Javascript code would "simulate" a click on every matching button.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the explanation.